# How to clone codeplex code with current changes in tortoiseSVN or tortoiseHG

Tags: asp.net, mercurial, codeplex

I want to download the code of nopcommorce with this changes

http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/f438f188fa4e

For get this I am going to clone the code and it's not make clone. I got error that

```
% hg clone --verbose -- https://hg.codeplex.com/nopcommerce .
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 1718536 bytes, expected 3694604)
[command returned code 255 Sat Oct 27 14:51:03 2012]
% hg clone --verbose -- https://hg.codeplex.com/nopcommerce .
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 997670 bytes, expected 5238782)
[command returned code 255 Sat Oct 27 14:53:37 2012]
```

Can someone tell me how I can got it worked. I have both tortoseHG and tortoiseSVN both installed..
how  I can got the code on my computer with the recent changes.

Answer (score 1):

- It's mercurial repo, you have to use only hg
- It's big repo, for such cases clone to some non-tip revision and set of pulls may work better (-r option for clone|pull)

`% hg clone --verbose -- https://hg.codeplex.com/nopcommerce .`

`requesting all changes`

`adding changesets`

`adding manifests`

`adding file changes`

`added 3021 changesets with 54579 changes to 15033 files (+6 heads)`

...

`4280 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved`

`[command completed successfully Sat Oct 27 15:48:37 2012]`